# Уведомления в Linux

Tags: linux

Задача: хочу настроить что бы на рабочем столе появлялись уведомления с нужным мне текстом. Текст может быть разным.

Имеем: ubuntu 16 с окружением xfce

В интернете нашел утилиту которая называется `notify-send` которая вроде работает, но я подключаюсь к рабочим машинам по `ssh` и в таком случае он уведомления не выводит, но если зайти с нужного компьютера в терминал, и там через терминал что-то вывести через `notify-send` - все работает. Тоесть проблема только в том что я подключаюся по `ssh`. Может есть какие-то аналоги? Или способ заставить это приложение выводить уведомления через `ssh`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46810043/6944845

Answer (score 0):

В современных системах

```
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/bus
notify-send "Test Test" "testing..."
```

Проверил на Debian 9 Stretch (это 2017 год, systemd). Древностей старше у меня нет.

Comment: ради интереса запустил live-образ ubuntu 16.04.7 в виртуалке и поднял там ssh-сервер. По итогу ваша конструкция не работает, а вот `DISPLAY=:0.0 notify-send test` работает

Comment: добавьте новый ответ, мой для систем после 2017 года на основе systemd. 16 убунту указанна в вопросе, но это ж древность... да и дисплей может отличаться, а тут попадание в юзера

Comment: ubuntu 16.04 тоже на systemd поэтому думаю дело не в этом, по поводу добавить в ответы то по идее это лучше сделать @tocic так как именно его ссылка под основным вопросом предоставляет верное решение.

Comment: systemd какое-то время был системой запуска сервисов, но в какойто момент стал операционной системой. DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS перенесли в XDG_RUNTIME_DIR

Comment: @Zt. там по ссылке нет моего ответа, потому я его и оставил как отдельный) если tocic не создаст ответ, то можно сделать общий ответ без рейтинга